# How to set a default cursor selection in a Listbox py3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this is my code, and it works fine When the program starts there is no selection in the listbox and I want to set a default selection in the listbox, for the case when a selection is not made by the user. any help, please!

```
### frame_3 widgets.
frame_3 = Frame(frame_2)
label_1a = Label(frame_3, relief = 'solid', width = 17)
label_1a.configure(text = "Start of Period month")
### listbow_1 and static attributes.
listbox_1 = Listbox(frame_3, exportselection=0, width = 12, height = 12)
for item in ['January','Febuary','March',
             'April','May','June',
             'July','August','September',
             'October','November','December']:
    listbox_1.insert(END,item)

label_2a = Label(frame_3, relief = 'groove', width = 10)
label_2a.configure(text = "Start day")
entry_1 = Entry(frame_3, width = 2)
### geometry frame_3
label_1a.grid (column = 0, row = 2)
frame_3.grid  (column = 0, row = 2)
listbox_1.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
label_2a.grid (column = 0, row = 5)
entry_1.grid  (column = 1, row = 5)
```

Comment: do want to change cursor type or what add more context to your question

Comment: Have you read any documentation or done any research? This is a pretty basic question, and there must be hundreds of examples on the internet for doing what you want to do. Also, please create a [mcve]. If your problem is with setting the selection of a listbox, all we need is code to display a listbox. All of t hose other labels, entries, and frames are irrelevant.

Comment: I could not find an example of how to set an item in a listbox as a default selection.

Comment: I have looked at plenty of examples of doing different stuff with listbox's, I could not find what I was looking and thats including this site!

Comment: @BryanOakley Oakley! do you have an answer though? I have done some research and looked at many examples, none of which had an example of how to set a default selection in a listbox.

Comment: when you will run code which get selected element from list then you can check if any element is selected and display window with warning or get first element from list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `listbox.selection_set(0)` to select first item on list

More in documentation: [Listbox.selection_set](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.selection_set-method)

Full example

```
import tkinter as tk

def test():
    # here you can get selected element
    print('previous:', listbox.get('active'))
    print(' current:', listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(1, 'Hello 1')
listbox.insert(2, 'Hello 2')
listbox.insert(3, 'Hello 3')
listbox.insert(4, 'Hello 4')
listbox.selection_set(0)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Test", command=test)
button.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer furas